# how to Execute a cmd file in my ps script?

Tags: deployment, powershell, windows-installer

I have a cmd file which calls an msi and passes paramters. I am calling this deploy.cmd file from a powershell script. How can i achive this?

I am may be missing something here.

This is what my cmd looks like,

```
Msiexec /i ABCInstaller.msi ^
DB.SERVER=ABC\QA ^
APPLICATION.ENV.TYPE=Qa ^
SVCIDENTITY=SVC-QA@ABC.com ^
SVCPASSWORD=xxx ^
LOCAL.EMAILING="true" ^
EMAIL.GMAT="tarun.arora@abc.com" ^
EMAIL.GMATR="tarun.arora@abc.com" ^
EMAIL.SUCCESSFUL.VALIDATION.SUBJECT="[QA] Successful validation of ABC Message" ^
/lv "ABC_Installer_QA_Log.txt"
```

This is what my powershell script looks like,

```
# Assigning Build Number and Drop Location for the MSI in scope
$buildNumber = $TfsDeployerBuildData.BuildNumber
$dropLocation = $TfsDeployerBuildData.DropLocation

# Assign values
if($buildNumber -eq $null)
{
$buildNumber = $args[0]
$dropLocation = $args[1]
}

# Move old uninstall folder to Archive folder 
Move-Item "D:\deploy\ABC_Uninstalled\*" "D:\deploy\ABC_Archive" -force 

# Move old build folder to uninstalled folder 
Move-Item "D:\deploy\ABC_Installed\*" "D:\deploy\ABC_Uninstalled" -force 

# Logging 
Add-Content -Path "C:\Log\TfsDeployer_Log.txt" -Value $dropLocation 
Add-Content -Path "C:\Log\TfsDeployer_Log.txt" -Value $buildNumber 

# Copy the msi from drop location to local physical drive 
Copy-Item $dropLocation "D:\deploy\ABC_Installed" -recurse 
Add-Content -Path "C:\Log\TfsDeployer_Log.txt" -Value "Copied the Msi to D:\deploy\Installed"

# Start execution 
& "D:\deploy\ABC_Installed\$buildNumber\en-us\ETRM_QA.cmd"
```

However when the ps is executed, It prints out what is inside the cmd file rather than executing it, so the output of the execution is

```
Output: C:\WINDOWS\system32>Msiexec /i ABCInstaller.msi ^
DB.SERVER=ABC\QA ^
APPLICATION.ENV.TYPE=Qa ^
SVCIDENTITY=SVC-QA@ABC.com ^
SVCPASSWORD=xxx ^
LOCAL.EMAILING="true" ^
EMAIL.GMAT="tarun.arora@abc.com" ^
EMAIL.GMATR="tarun.arora@abc.com" ^
EMAIL.SUCCESSFUL.VALIDATION.SUBJECT="[QA] Successful validation of ABC Message" ^
/lv "ABC_Installer_QA_Log.txt" /passive T
```

The cmd file is not executed :-(

Comment: If i create a simple cmd file (Copy.cmd) which does the following,
Xcopy "C:\Folder 1"  ^
"C:\Folder 2"
And call it in powershell script
"C:\Copy.cmd" 
It works.
However if you tend to use Msiexec it just prints the cmd file rather than executing it. So if my (copy.cmd) contains the following
Msiexec /i EtrmInstaller.msi
And the powershell script is
& "C:\Folder 1\Copy.cmd"

Then the output is C:\Documents and Settings\tarora\My Documents>Msiexec /i EtrmInstaller.msi

But nothing is executed!


C:\Documents and Settings\tarora\My Documents>Msiexec /i EtrmInstaller.msi

Tp

Comment: Tip: having a more readable question might yield more answers

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Invoke-Expression "D:\deploy\ABC_Installed\$buildNumber\en-us\ETRM_QA.cmd"
```

Answer (score 0):

MsiExec likely is executing, you are just not seeing it because it launches as a background process that immediately returns control to cmd. For example, if I create a cmd script that looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\WINWORD.EXE"
```

And invoke it like this:

```
&launchWord.cmd
```

All I see on the powershell console is the contents of the cmd script, but word opens in another window.
Are you sure msiexec isn't just launching and failing, rather than failing to launch?